# How do I convert this raw SQL to Arel query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

In a Rails(3.2) app, I have a class method on a Model like this:

```
def import(level, max = 10)
  db = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  result = db.execute("SELECT word FROM levels WHERE level == #{level} AND word NOT IN (SELECT entry FROM words) limit #{max};");
```

It just imports 10 new words(create 10 records) at a time that do not exist as Word record yet.

The schema looks something like this:

```
create_table "levels", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "word"
  t.integer "level"
end

create_table "words", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "entry"
  t.integer "level",      :default => 0
  t.text    "definition"
  t.string  "thesaurus",  :default => "none"
end
```

I'm an SQL noob. Messing with rails dbconsole(sqlite3, I'm using sqlite3 on a server as well), I somehow came up with the raw sql query above. I sort of know that I can do the same thing with Arel. How am I supposed to construct the query with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (untested) should work.  It uses [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) in the subquery.

```
Level.where(:level => level).where("word NOT IN (?)", Word.pluck(:entry)).limit(max)
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea, but `Level.where("word NOT IN ?", "apple,banana")` yields: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: apple,banana: SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels"  WHERE (word NOT IN 'apple,banana').` Hmmm.

Comment: I think if you take out the `join(",")` at the end it should work. The `IN` interpolation wants an array.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out myself. `Level.where(:level => level).where("word NOT IN (?)", Word.pluck(:entry)).limit(max)` works. You need `()` around the `?` as well. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

@Gazler's solution looks like it works, but I'll provide an alternative using `MetaWhere` syntax which is a bit more concise:

```rb
Level.where(:level => level, :word.not_in => Word.pluck(:entry)).limit(max)
```

Comment: Beautiful. But, I get this error: 'NoMethodError: undefined method `not_in' for :word:Symbol'. Where does this not_in method belong??

Comment: Oh, I need a gem named [MetaWhere](http://erniemiller.org/projects/metawhere/)? Is it going to land on Rails in the near future? If not, I will just stick with @Gazler's solution. Thanks, anyways!

Comment: Hmm... funny. It seems to be built in to the version of Rails I'm using (3.0.7). I'll have to be careful with it if it's been taken out already...

Comment: On the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where#readme), the author of the gem states 'There were extensive changes to ActiveRecord between Rails 3.0 and 3.1, and *MetaWhere will not be updated to support 3.1.*'. It doesn't work with 3.2 and above. Instead, he seems to be working on [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), which does the same magic.